# System.DateTime.ParseExact error in SOAP response in Monotouch iOS

Tags: datetime, soap, mono, xamarin.ios, xml-serialization

I have an application that is making SOAP web service calls to another application (no JSON possibility here).  Some of the responses come back fine.  The issue is that one of the calls is made OK but the response brings back a `System.DateTime.ParseExact` error.  I checked the date format in SOAPUI and it came back as: `2012-02-05-05:00`

The error message is:

> at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String[] formats, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x0005c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1761 
>     at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider, DateTimeStyles style) [0x0001c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:1741 
>     at System.DateTime.ParseExact (System.String s, System.String format, IFormatProvider provider) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System/DateTime.cs:927 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.FromXmlString (System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData type, System.String value) [0x001d4] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlCustomFormatter.cs:275 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.GetValueFromXmlString (System.String value, System.Xml.Serialization.TypeData typeData, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap) [0x00047] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:652 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadPrimitiveValue (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x0003e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:638 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x0003f] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:614 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList, Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x0082c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:464 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:240 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x000d5] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:230 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00031] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00076] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:220 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00031] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x0005c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:620 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList, Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x005fb] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:434 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstanceMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, System.Object ob) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:240 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadClassInstance (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x000d5] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:230 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObject (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapping typeMap, Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType) [0x00031] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:193 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadObjectElement (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeMapElementInfo elem) [0x0005c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:620 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMembers (System.Xml.Serialization.ClassMap map, System.Object ob, Boolean isValueList, Boolean readBySoapOrder) [0x005fb] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:434 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadMessage (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlMembersMapping typeMap) [0x0015a] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:154 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.ReadRoot () [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializationReaderInterpreter.cs:92 
>     at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader reader) [0x0001c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlSerializer.cs:361

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not look like a question (see note) but, in case I'm mistaken, here why...

```
case "date": return DateTime.ParseExact (value, "yyyy-MM-dd", null);
```

That's line #275 from [XmlCustomFormatter.cs](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.XML/System.Xml.Serialization/XmlCustomFormatter.cs#L275) (source available on github) that shows the format (right or wrong) that Mono expect the date to be.

This does not match the `2012-02-05-05:00` string you provided in your question and this leads to the exception you're now experiencing. This could be a bug in Mono or, if Microsoft implementation behave the same, an issue with the web service you're calling.

**note:** bug reports be filled at http://bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have an ASP.NET version of the application and I do not have this issue.  Exact same code and web service.  This seems to be a Mono bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the this before a couple years back, it has stopped me porting several web service projects to Mono. I can confirm Mono behaves differently than than Microsoft .Net. I am not clear if it is a bug, but many web services return the date in formats other than 'yyyy-mm-dd', some add a 'Z' or other timezone spec, some have the time. You could patch Mono to use System.DateTime.Parse, but that a pain to have to use a custom Mono build just for this.